# Common record fetch from table in two dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have problem when i want fetch data from sql table(common for both dropdownlist) & i want this way...
our common record is

```
id city
1 Pune
2 Mumbai
3 Delhi
4 Kolkata
```

Sourse-ddl1- if we select "Pune"
Destination-ddl2-Here should be come all cities except pune.

both record comes from common table id ,city but no one record should be match in both table.

Comment: bind Sencond Drop down Using `select * from City where CityCode Not IN (select CityCode from CityCode="ddl2.selectedValue")`

Comment: Thanks i am just trying ..

Answer (score 0):

In the first dropdownlist

select * from City where CityCode!=ddl2.selectedValue

whereas in the second dropdown

select * from City where CityCode!=ddl1.selectedValue

Comment: please tell me where we can put exactly i am new for .net.